# Draw a path between two coordinates using MapKit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, maps

All the answers on SO for this question are using Objective-c, or using Swift 2. Any way I have two points, the coordinates for the first one is (lat, long), and for the second point (coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude). This is what I was able to get so far, but still I have two problems:

```
Value of type 'MKDirectionsRequest' has no member 'setSource'
Value of type 'MKDirectionsRequest' has no member 'setDestination'
```

Any way I got this code from this page:http://studyswift.blogspot.com/2014/10/mkdirections-draw-route-from-location.html

This is my code so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myMap: MKMapView!
var myRoute : MKRoute?
```

Inside `viewDidLoad` I have the following:

```
let directionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
        let markFirstPoint = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long), addressDictionary: nil)
        let markSecondPoint = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude), addressDictionary: nil)
        directionsRequest.setSource(MKMapItem(placemark: markSecondPoint))
        directionsRequest.setDestination(MKMapItem(placemark: markFirstPoint))
        directionsRequest.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.automobile
        let directions = MKDirections(request: directionsRequest)
        directions.calculate { (response:MKDirectionsResponse!, error: Error!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                self.myRoute = response.routes[0] as? MKRoute
                self.myMap.add((self.myRoute?.polyline)!)
            }
        }
```

after `viewDidLoad` I have this:

```
 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
        var myLineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: (myRoute?.polyline)!)
        myLineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
        myLineRenderer.lineWidth = 3
        return myLineRenderer
    }
```

Is there any way I can get this code to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply look at the documentation for `MKDirectionsRequest`. There is a `source` property and a `destination` property.

The lines:

```
directionsRequest.setSource(MKMapItem(placemark: markSecondPoint))
directionsRequest.setDestination(MKMapItem(placemark: markFirstPoint))
```

become:

```
directionsRequest.source = MKMapItem(placemark: markSecondPoint)
directionsRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: markFirstPoint)
```

Comment: Thanks man, it worked. but during the run time it gave me this error: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional `
At this line: `self.myMap.add((self.myRoute?.polyline)!)`

Comment: That's an entirely separate issue that you should post a separate question for. But before you do, thoroughly review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu